How to give someone access to product workspace tab salesforce
This seemingly simple question has me confused.
We have a permission that we'd like to give users visibility into the store and subsequent commerce objects. The permission set has access to the Product2 object that is used in the Product Workspace tab, but I cannot get them to see that in the app despite Product Workspace added to the app.
It does not look like there is a way to specifically assign access to the Product Workspace to the permission set via Object/App/Visualforce Page, unless I missed somthing? Is there dependent objects that need to be added?
Looked for documentation on this but could not find anything.
